# Questions related to Instagram oauth on ios

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api, universal-link

I'm going to add an Instagram oauth service on my app.

However, problems arise in the iOS environment.

api provided by Instagram (https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize)

The Instagram app runs first, and then the safari browser runs. And the authentication for Instagram is executed in the Safari browser.

Therefore, a problem arises. Interworking fails if you are not logged in to our service in the safari browser.

Don't I have an option to authenticate without running an Instagram app?

Summary: I don't want Instagram app to run when using Instagram oauth-api in my service.

Comment: Can you provide more details around "Interworking fails" ?

Comment: @AndrewL My service supports both the app and the web.
Run My App -> Click Instagram Authentication button in My App -> Run Instagram App -> Proceed Instagram Authentication in Safari browser.

It proceeds in this order. At this time, authentication cannot be performed unless the safari browser is web-logged in. This phenomenon occurs only in ios.

Comment: I would open a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create/

Comment: @MSS Did you found any solution to this? If you have created a bug in FB can you paste that link here? I am also running into same issue, but in my case we are having an Application form and user can connect their IG account in that form but the form works on iframe and opens auth page in new tab after going through in-app flow and when it returns with code it blanks out the form. I have authentication flow working well with Twitter, Tiktok and Facebook only IG having issues and that only in Mobile browser in desktop it's working fine.